# Reset CSS in a media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Lets say I have a media query..

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
 /*STYLE HERE */
}
```

Is it possible to reset the CSS within this media query so that none of the elements in it receive styling from the default stylesheet?

Help would definitely be appreciated!!

Comment: Other than setting all properties to their initial value (and using a more specific selector if needed) it isn't. Eventually though, the [`all`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#all-shorthand) shorthand would be used to do such a thing.

Comment: What about wrapping the rules in the default stylesheet to `max-width: 959px`?

Comment: Yes. You just have to reset them. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Those resets are annoying if what OP really wants is to get back to the browser's default styles, not a zero-margin, zero-padding, etc version of everything.  I would have said what @Suvi said.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to achieve such a thing, load stylesheets with queries :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 959x)' href='mobile.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 960px)' href='desktop.css' />
```

I don't recommend that you have two different stylesheet with repeated style/layout, as it will become very hard to manage in a larger project.

Instead I suggest going with a mobile first main stylesheet (or query) where you apply basic mobile layout, color and style etc. You then code the layout for the rest of the sheets/queries (tablet->desktop). Most of the time going up a query will require simple columns adjustment and some padding/margin, font size etc, so most of your main styling is used everywhere.